# How To get different NMEA Strings like Gps ans sensor toolkit app

Tags: java, android, gps, nmea

I am writing an app for android but when it use `onNmeaReceived(String nmea, long timestamp)` , I only get one string. But when I use [Gps and sensor toolkit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kennis.gsat) app on android it gives a wealth of different nmea strings, even ones like qzgsv, etc... Why?

Comment: Aren't you receiving different NMEA sentences through many calls to onNmeaReceived? There is a special API for GPS on Android, you might probably want to start there.

Comment: to my knowledge you can only override a method once